# Chef template file file not found

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, berkshelf

My vagrant failed when provisioning with template.

```
template "/var/.s3cfg" do
  source "s3cfg.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0644"
end
```

in that cookbook directory, file `templates/default/s3cfg.erb` exists.

**But strangely it's work successfully on opswork amazon**, so it might be vagrant, vagrant-cachier, vagrant-berkshelf, berkshelf, or  chef error.

Any idea how to check?

My environment:

```
$: vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.6.5

$: vagrant plugin list
vagrant-berkshelf (3.0.1)
vagrant-cachier (0.9.0)
vagrant-login (1.0.1, system)
vagrant-omnibus (1.4.1)
vagrant-share (1.1.1, system)

$: chef -v
Chef Development Kit Version: 0.2.2

$: berks -v
3.1.5
```

vagrant box is ubuntu-precise 12.04

Comment: I commonly need to start backing out vagrant plugins when I see oddness like this. This is easy enough as they install/uninstall quickly enough.  I would start with vagrant-cachier as that is more of a nicety for speed.  If you get something reproducible be sure to log with the appropriate project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the cause is because `chef` default location of provisioning path located at `/tmp/vagrant-chef`. In the middle of the chef execution, somehow the `/tmp/` folder cleaned. Hence the missing file.

By changing the location of `chef.provisioning_path` to other folder than `/tmp/`, it worked normally.